# php lista con ul y li

Tags: php

Tengo que generar esta lista con números impares y múltiplos de del 5, ponerlo el resultado en una pagina web. Esto es lo que llevo de código, no se como poner los múltiplos en color rojo

[image: lista]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
           $i = 1;     
           $n = 50;   
           $impar = 1;
           $mult = 3;
            while ( $i <= $n){
                echo "<ul> <li>".$impar."</li></ul>";
                $i = $i + 1;
                $impar = $impar + 2;
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema que tienes en el codigo que no esta explicado en el contexto de la pregunta? Al correr el codigo genera los numero impares del 1 al 99

Comment: Si, esa parte de poner impares ya sale, el problemas es que no se como pintar los multiplos del 5 en color rojo

Comment: ok entiendo, ya te ayudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Respuesta:**

1) Debes colocar una condicion `if()` que evalue el modulo % de 5 cuando tengas los multiplos impares, si el resultado de la divicion de 5 es 0 por resultado del modulo entonces muestra un `<li>` con estilo de color rojo.

2) Se organizo la estructura afuera del  para que construya solo los items los `<li>`

Aqui te ajunto el codigo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
           $i = 1;     
           $n = 50;   
           $impar = 1;
           $mult = 3;
           echo '<ul>'; 
                while ( $i <= $n){
                    if ($impar%5 == 0) {
                        echo '<li style="color:red">'.$impar. '</li>';
                    } else {
                        echo "<li>".$impar."</li>";
                    }

                    $i = $i + 1;
                    $impar = $impar + 2;
                }
            echo '</ul>';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

La salida del codigo es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias, no tenia ni idea de como pintar los múltiplos de 3

Comment: Siempre a la orden y califica la respuesta como positiva

Answer (score 2):

Esto se puede hacer de una forma más sencilla del siguiente modo:

1. Usando un `for` que, empiece en `1`, llegue hasta `100` (números impares hasta el 100), incremente de dos en dos
2. Usar un ternario para preguntar si es múltiplo de 5 o no, agregando el estilo rojo a la variable `$html` que irá concatenando todo.
3. Imprimir al final

**Código:**

```
$html="<ul>";
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i+=2){
    $html.= ($i%5 == 0) ? "<li style=\"color:red\">$i</li>" : "<li>$i</li>";
}
$html.="</ul>";
echo $html;
```

**Ejemplo de la salida en pantalla:**

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li style="color:red">5</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li style="color:red">15</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li style="color:red">25</li>
  <li>27</li>
  <li>29</li>
  <li>31</li>
  <li>33</li>
  <li style="color:red">35</li>
  <li>37</li>
  <li>39</li>
  <li>41</li>
  <li>43</li>
  <li style="color:red">45</li>
  <li>47</li>
  <li>49</li>
  <li>51</li>
  <li>53</li>
  <li style="color:red">55</li>
  <li>57</li>
  <li>59</li>
  <li>61</li>
  <li>63</li>
  <li style="color:red">65</li>
  <li>67</li>
  <li>69</li>
  <li>71</li>
  <li>73</li>
  <li style="color:red">75</li>
  <li>77</li>
  <li>79</li>
  <li>81</li>
  <li>83</li>
  <li style="color:red">85</li>
  <li>87</li>
  <li>89</li>
  <li>91</li>
  <li>93</li>
  <li style="color:red">95</li>
  <li>97</li>
  <li>99</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Excelente aporte y buen codigo, has simplificado en la rutina, Ahora el OP tiene 2 respuestas para apoyarse...